# What is the appropriate way to report someone who created a new account to get around a ban?

Tags: support, post-ban, sock-puppets

If a user asks a question, but it is closed and the account (for some reason) is banned, what is the appropriate way to report this account and the relevant question? This happened just today (as some of you may actually have caught) and the person created a new account asking the exact same question.

But for these kinds of cases, where there is reason to suspect a user has created a new account to ask the same question, what is the appropriate way to report it?

Comment: Since noone other than someone with elected moderator powers and above can handle it, a custom flag would likely be the only meaningful tool to use.

Comment: Please note that Meta is *not* an appropriate place to report someone you suspect of evading a ban. You need to report it confidentially to moderators with a custom flag.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Flag the question for moderator attention and be as specific and detailed as you can in *why* you think this person may be evading the ban. Only "this user is evading a ban" isn't very useful for a moderator; whereas "this is a sock of [this banned user](http://ksassets.timeincuk.net/wp/uploads/sites/55/2015/11/2-15JustinBieber_Hero_Lead_111115.hero_-1.jpg) and I believe they're evading a ban because <reasons>" *is*!.

You've got 500 characters, *use 'em*!