# Is it possible (or meaningful) to forbid someone to create a new account to get past a ban?

Tags: discussion, post-ban, duplicate-accounts

Recently this question has been on Meta:

- [What is the appropriate way to report someone who created a new account to get around a ban?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349499/what-is-the-appropriate-way-to-report-someone-who-created-a-new-account-to-get-a)

To me that particular issue there seems like a duplicate question problem, but it raises the whole issue of circumventing bans by creating a new account. On several occasions I've seen people say that you shouldn't create a new account in order to get past the question ban. This seems strange to me. It is like asking people boarding a plane if they are terrorists. The good people aren't and the bad people say they aren't. A conscientious Stack Overflow user may refrain from opening a second account, but a spammer will have no qualms about it. By forbidding it you are only inhibiting the conscientious user.

The more official stance actually seems to be "yes you can do it but you may be punished for it." (See what Shog wrote [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285981/3681880), quoting [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255584/3681880).)

> ### Can I simply create a new account?
>
> Yes, but doing so violates the rules for operating multiple accounts -
>   namely, [it allows you to do something you would otherwise be
>   restricted from
>   doing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange).
>   Penalties for violating this restriction can vary:
>
> - Your accounts may be deleted without warning.
> - You *and others on your network* may find your questions are shown to fewer potential answerers or subjected to preemptive review when
>     posted.
> - You *and others on your network* may be prevented from asking questions entirely.
> - If you opt to [*delete* your account](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account) and then
>     later return to the site, your ability to ask questions may be
>     [limited to one question per
>     week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234610/102937) until you have demonstrated an ability to ask useful questions.

This is a site for programmers. As programmers we are constantly looking for solutions to problems. We keep trying things until something works. That applies to question bans. If I have a pressing issue that I need help with, then I'm not going to wait a month or even a week to ask it. I'll find a way to get help sooner.

Even the penalties listed above are rather meaningless. If a user's accounts get deleted, then they can open a new one with a new email address. If you limit or block their network, then they can find a new IP by using a VPN or proxy. Most Stack Overflow users in China pretty much have to do this already because of [the blocked Google APIs that SE uses](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258288/use-of-ajax-googleapis-com-not-china-friendly).

Don't get me wrong, I'm all for rate limits and bans and everything else used to cut down on the number of poor questions coming in. I'm also not talking about sock puppet voting or other types of multiple account abuse. I just think that telling people not to open a new account when they have a question ban is not useful. Or even if it is in some way meaningful, it is not practically enforceable.

In my opinion, the biggest deterrent to creating a new account is that you lose all your rep and the privileges that come with it. This is a natural consequence that no one needs to remind you of.

Comment: Full disclosure: This is my second account. My first one got banned while I was still figuring out how Stack Overflow worked. I will be sad if you delete this account now. But I would just open another one.

Comment: The conscientious users with question bans that you're worried about should also be the people who read the guidance to edit and improve their questions, therefore removing their ban. I'm not sure what you expect SE to say here—it'd undermine the point of the ban to say "just create another account; we'll let you ask again". The users who just keep asking *terrible* questions will find that they just get question banned, **every time**, unless they improve, in which case there aren't any problems. I would imagine after being banned *multiple* times, many people just get bored and stop.

Comment: Question bans are just parking tickets, not county-jail.  Mostly useful to create the illusion that something is being done about persistent bad-question askers.  The more we talk about it, the less useful the illusion becomes.

Comment: related: [So you got banned? No problem, just create a new account (or not?)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284271/839601)

Comment: per my reading of [comments in related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284271/so-you-got-banned-no-problem-just-create-a-new-account-or-not#comment152354_284271) prior wording was softer and this made some misread as it is officially allowed to create new account (and not just technically possible). Current wording seems to be there only to prevent misreading like that, not to really make it harder (the latter is doable too but not this way, and it's not being done likely because [it would make Spolsky sad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296166/839601))

Comment: For what it's worth, you're not likely to get banned just for opening a second account. You'd have to continue the same behavior that got the first account banned. It looks like you learned the right lessons from your first account, so you should have nothing to worry about.

Comment: To your point "If I have a pressing issue that I need help with, then I'm not going to wait a month or even a week to ask it. "...  SO isn't a help immediately on demand site;  it is a Question and Answer repository.  Sure, many of the questions get answered within a few hours or a few days, but that doesn't mean that every question should be treated like a pressing matter, and in fact, questions that are time sensitive are much less likely to be well written, researched questions in the first place.

Comment: @Aurora0001 (1/2) I've seen cases of users that simply can't evade the question ban. They've asked a really poorly received question or two to begin with, then a few good ones, still tripped a ban, deleted the bad questions, and improved the good ones. But because deleted questions still count for the ban and they are so fundamentally flawed they cannot be improved to lift the ban, they're limited to only asking 1 question every 6 months until they get enough to counteract the first couple of bad ones.

Comment: @Aurora0001 (2/2) At this point, it's simply easier to start a second account off on the right foot.

Comment: I say just let people create new accounts, just make the new accounts hidden from everyone else. That way they have no idea they've wasted all their time and won't go creating third/fourth/etc accounts. :)

Answer (score 26):

This was the reason I asked [this earlier question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324220/should-stack-overflow-be-more-restrictive-about-new-user-registrations). We know that people create question-ban evasion accounts all the time, so I wanted to kick around ideas for how to make this harder or how to detect these accounts as they happen. On a near-daily basis, I find and delete question-ban evasion accounts and / or deal with sock puppets created to prop someone up from being banned. The discussion on that question went in a bit of a different direction, though.

When someone evading a question ban is brought to my attention, I can usually track down the main account and all their secondary accounts. Feeding the secondary accounts into the anti-trolling system (a process [I'd like to see codified and made simpler](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295429/streamlining-deletion-of-quality-block-evasion-accounts)) works to block new accounts from their location.

Despite what you might think, and what you speculate about in your question, I've found that intelligent IP-bans put in place by this system work extremely well to stop further posts by question-ban evaders. The people dumping questions on the site in order to have us do their work for them are not exactly the most capable or hard-working programmers, so they aren't as likely to take the time to figure out how to circumvent these blocks. I've seen tags transformed overnight by catching and IP-blocking a few repeated question-ban evaders. Their posts stopped immediately.

Now, [Shog9's stats](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324244/19679) seem to indicate that the rate at which people evade question bans is far lower than the rate at which genuinely new accounts are posting, so I don't know if it's just my irritation with these folks causing me to focus on them or if they are a legitimate problem.

There might still be things that the site could do to cut down on this, like banning throwaway email providers for new account registration (mailinator, 10-minute-mail, sharklasers, etc.), identifying new accounts on IPs where someone was just question-banned, identifying new accounts with names that match others on the same IP, and so on. That's what I'd hoped to discuss in my earlier question, but the conversation focused more on brand new users than on ban evaders. I might propose some of these as separate feature requests if I can think through the implementation.

Comment: I wasn't looking at it from a moderator's perspective in my question. I'm in favor of putting these sort of practical impediments into place.

Comment: @Suragch - I was attempting to address the commonly-expressed notion that we can't stop people from evading these bans, and that the only people we stop are the more law-abiding users. Looking at this from a non-moderator perspective, that would appear to be the case, but in my observation question bans are pretty effective at stopping a first tier of users and intelligent IP bans take care of almost all the rest. Only a tiny fraction of people work around that. It doesn't seem like it should work this well, but it does. I'd just like to do more to catch this before that second level.

Comment: @BradLarson Isn't this vulnerable to the [Survivorship bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivorship_bias)? You're saying the current approach works because you've caught 100% of the accounts that you've caught.

Comment: @Rob - I'm not saying we're catching 100% of question-ban evaders (that's clearly not the case, just as we don't catch 100% of those defrauding the voting system). The people evading question bans are reasonably easy to identify using our various moderator tools and by the style and content of the questions they ask. Most are brought to our attention by the community, particularly in small tags, where they ask the same bad questions in the same style. We feel pretty confident that we've stopped someone when we see no new accounts and the community sees no more questions from them.

Comment: The regulars in a tag (particularly smaller ones) have a pretty good sense for when they've seen a style of question before, or see the same variable names, etc. Moderators also follow up on question-ban evaders to make sure they aren't creating new accounts. The regularity with which we see immediate falloffs in bad questions within a tag after IP blocks are put in place gives me the confidence to say that this works well as a means of stopping ban evaders. Question ban evaders usually aren't the sharpest knives in the drawer, so they're not creating elaborate plans to hide from us.

Comment: At least mailinator seems to be banned already. Just tried creating a quick throwaway account to test some UI thing for new users and I get "CoolBummer@mailinator.com is not a valid email address.".

Comment: Speaking on small tags and recognizing grammar, I found someone posting a question on SO that I recognized from *an entirely different website forum* (and under a different name) where I'd mashed the ignore button so I wouldn't have to deal with their stupidity.  No surprise, their question remains unanswered here as well. I also recently recognized a duplicate question from a second account (though with no evidence of question ban, just...someone doing something weird, still wrong, just weird). I reported it to a moderator to deal with because it was more involved than simply being a dup.

Comment: Are there any safeguards against false positives (people who match the IP-ban but are legitimate new users)?

Comment: @Nobody (I know the comment is old but) IP ban only rate-limit, not complete ban.

Answer (score 3):

If I may, I would like to answer this because I was one user who got banned. And if I may, I would like to tell my story because It might help you understand my answer.

This is actually my first account; I created a second account because I forgot my password on this account, which I eventually discovered later on.

On my banned account I was one of those programmers who asked "personal" questions. I would define personal questions as "questions which are completely vague and/or could only be answered by the questioner".

Most people would ask me to read the guidelines of SE. I did read the guidelines but I still could not manage how to ask properly; some say it is still vague, others say that there are similar questions, others still say that its completely useless. In my defense, I asked those questions because I think I had narrowed it down to what I really need. But people insisted to narrow it even more. I found it confusing.

I also had vague answers which contributed to my ban, these vague answers lacks ways on how I solved it. A reviewer told me it really does not have the steps on how I completed the task, or what does the code really do. All of these contributed to my ban.

You might be asking, why do I still stick with this site?

After my ban I tried other sites which I think are relevant on what my problem needs. But most sites does not give me answers; other are completely blank, its like a dead forum. Here in SE, there are plenty of online users that are ready to help, some are pros in the field. And answers come quickly and as precisely on what you need, you just have to learn how to ask.

I really did find out it was really hard to ask a precise and clean question. It even led to a ban of one of my accounts. But, I really need the knowledge here in this forum to solve my problems (after research and testing of course, asking a question right even before you did something is ..... )

So what did I do to redeem myself?

I think now I'm getting good at asking and answering questions (I still need to fix my grammar though) When I ask, I trim it down to what I really need, review my phrase and edit it before posting. I also include the things which I already did and the output which I would like. In answering questions, I include step-by-step procedures on how to do it, and I include comments in my code for reference. There are still times that there are people who think my questions are still vague, but its not that much compared to my banned account.

My point would be:

There are others like me, who think that asking questions here in SE is as easy as asking what is the menu for dinner, and answering questions would be as easy as up, up, down, down, left, right, start, select, and the site would ban them. May the administrators give us more time, maybe 1 or 2 accounts more, to improve ourselves in asking questions. After all, we are programmers, because SE is one of the sites where you could get a clean answer, and it is one of the tools we need to solve our difficult questions.

Comment: I shared some similarities with your situation. It takes quite a while to learn how to ask a good question. By the time I did learn, my banned account was too crippled for me to progress at the rate I needed. Starting with a second account was not so that I could continue to ask bad questions, but so that I could start asking better (though not perfect) questions with a clean slate.

Comment: _"it was really hard to ask a precise and clean question"_, and _"May the administrators give us more time"_ -- IMHO, it's important to put yourself in the shoes of the people who are mostly answering questions. Even with the rules as they are today, the site is inundated by large volumes of useless or lazy (i.e. "write the code for me") questions. To make matters worse, many of these get upvoted in spite of their poor quality. Giving "more time" will just make things worse.

Comment: Also, by putting yourself in the shoes of the answerer, or even spending time answering, you'll have a much better sense for what's needed in a good question. In fact, it might not be a bad idea for people struggling to write good questions, to spend some time trying to answer bad ones.

Comment: I think if you answer a bad question with a bad answer repetitively, you still get banned for it, The site really urges you to ask a good question and write a good answer, which for me, really took a long time before I managed to create one, and I have to get banned before I do so. Its a win win actually if a person learns how to ask and answer clean questions.

Comment: So what was it, did you forget the password or were you banned from asking questions?  Maybe you decided to forget the password?  It is just easier not to spin a tale.

Comment: @HansPassant I think what Mr. J meant was the account he posted this answer as was his *original* account, which he forgot the password to (but later recovered).  While he didn't have access to this account he created a second, and *that* account go question-banned. It was after the ban that he recovered the password to the account he's now using.

Comment: @Draco18s precisely.

Comment: "up, up, down, down, left, right, start, select" - If you're referencing the Capcom code here, you're missing a few button presses ;)

Comment: Konami code, not Capcom.