# How should I deal with a user who repeatedly creates new accounts to ask poor questions?

Tags: discussion, accounts, abuse, duplicate-accounts

I have an enormous issue with something that is going on in the tag I watch.

It's been a few months now that a certain user creates new accounts **continually** to ask poor questions. As someone who watches the tag almost daily and who has a good eye for patterns, it seems this person is basically developing a web server by asking a question on Stack Overflow at **every step of the way**.

The reasons I have an issue with this are several:

- their questions get often downvoted and closed for being unclear, off topic or otherwise of little lasting value
- the question quality does not improve over time
- they often delete and re-ask, thus invalidating the comments and/or answers already gotten on previous questions
- they continually create new accounts, and rinse and repeat. I have counted a dozen already.

By doing this they waste the time of the answerers who engage with their questions, and take up space on the front page. I must note that some answerers may engage out of pure kindness and they may not see this as a waste of time, but still...

Obviously [I can mod-flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349499/what-is-the-appropriate-way-to-report-someone-who-created-a-new-account-to-get-a) and I do mod-flag. Including the necessary info about what I believe is their main account, and previous questions. Even if I'm under 10k, I have the links to deleted questions in my flag history.

I don't know if they do this because their main account is question-banned. It might be just the way they wish to use the site.

In all cases, I believe this behavior is close to abuse. However the mod-flags I raise do not get handled in time (there are 4 pending now) and they just merrily continue on their path.

I don't know if there's a definitive solution to this. I will just keep casting my votes as appropriate and flagging for moderator attention.

I'm posting to meta in the hope to:

- draw diamond attention to the pending flags
- draw the attention of my fellow tag watchers to this problem, in case they didn't notice (some did), and in case they want to help with the flagging.

I'm not going to post requests on SOCVR, as not all questions are obviously close-worthy. In some cases you need expertise with the tag. And anyway account-based shenanigans have to be handled by diamonds.

Anyway, if anyone has better advice other than "vote, flag and move on", you're welcome to post it.

Comment: I think you are handling the situation appropriately. I don't see what else you can do, if the user is creating new accounts with different credentials, and I think there is little SO can do either. It's just one of those situations that require patience since they have to be treated on a case by case basis.

Comment: They could potentially do an IP block, though that probably requires staff intervention, and assumes the user isn't using a VPN

Comment: @Zoe, that is the problerm, a VPN would easily get around the block, but I guess it wouldn't hurt too much, but for the matter of dynamic IPs, we can be blocking a future user that has nothing to do with this, though this would be highly unlikely.

Comment: @anastaciu I would prefer this user to get away with it until mod-flags come through instead of having an unrelated user banned for nothing

Comment: @blackgreen about the matter of the delayed flag handling, keep in mind that mods have a lot of flags to handle, sometimes it takes time, but they will eventually be handled, again, it's a matter of patience. Let's hope that the new mods can help on reducing the mod flag queues.

Comment: you handled all, that you can do, but if they are question banned, what else can they do, it is not so that there bad questions are eliminated or ignored over time. So imho let them be close them as you see fit and let it be,

Comment: I disagree, @nbk , if a user is creating *new* accounts to avoid a question ban, that needs to be addressed, and flagging those is the correct course. On the other hand, downvoting and VTCing should be based on the content of the question, not that the OP has created their 20th account to complete their transformation into a [[meta-tag:help-vampire]].

Comment: @Larnu some people are not able to ask godd question and some never will be, there should be for such people a bail out option.  A ban within a reasonable time should be enough for the time being. Besides isn't there an algorithm in pace to detect socketpuppets. Also as long as tehy don't do harm, lepp them coming

Comment: *"some people are not able to ask godd question"* then, with respect, [so] isn't the right place for them. There are other websites where their userbase are more than happy to *geif peoplez da codez* when they ask for it. *"Also as long as tehy don't do harm, lepp them coming"* but they *are* doing harm. Low quality content is the complete opposite of the goal that sites in the network want to achieve. They want high quality content, which includes both questions and answers. Low quality content harms that goal from being achieved.

Comment: "some people are not able to ask good question and some never will be," - Then those people will not be allowed to ask questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Asking is a privilege, not a right, @nbk . And [so], and the other sites in the community, aren't "help forums" like people think. Never has been, never will be. That isn't elitism. That's you, and other people, not understanding the site you are using.

Comment: no asking can everybody that has an account with 1 rep, so it is a right and not a privilege, if you are searching for privileges go to the collectoves

Comment: Wrong again, @nbk, there are plenty of people with 1 reputation that can't ask. Why? Because they have been question banned due to low quality content. I really suggest posting a question about this here on meta, the users here will be happy to give you more details, as this is the wrong place.

Comment: @nbk - Users who are question banned, did ask questions, it was just determined based on a pattern of asking questions that were not well received that they will only be able to ask a question every 6 months.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As has been mentioned in the comments, what you're doing is already the right thing. If you have good evidence that 2 users are the same user, and it appears the new user was created to try to avoid a post ban then creating a custom mod flag is exactly what you should be doing. Ensure that when you flag the question/answer you include as much information as possible; links to the other user and posts that you feel demonstrate that they are the same person are a must. If there isn't enough space, you could create an unlisted pastebin (or similar) and link to that in the flag.

As for the question/answer, judge that on it's own. If you feel it is worth a Downvote, do so. If you think it should be closed, vote to close. But judge the question in solitude. Don't downvote/VTC because you believe the user is avoiding a post ban *(though if it's an exact dupe of a prior deleted post from different, but suspected same, user I suspect no tears will be shed if your cursor "accidentally" clicked on the downvote button)*. If the question is good, upvote it, or even answer it.

After that, that's all you can do. The mods will handle it when they can. Yes, some of these flags take a little time, but such flags often need a little investigation too, and that *might* require a CM (I don't know what Mods can and can't see) which will inevitably slow down the flag handling.

As for the user, if the posts are low quality, they'll need get *another* question ban, and need to create *another* account. I would not be surprised if they eventually get tired of doing that alone (we can hope).

If people want to answer the questions, then (unfortunately?) so be it; some users are more generous with low quality questions, and "give me the codes" style posts than I. I, personally, don't feel such answers help Stack Overflow achieve its goal(s), but that is a very different topic (but still for Meta). At some point the user is going to be either found out by their tutor, manager, etc (they always do) or swimming way out of their depth and drown (and again exposed).

Note: If you see a post from a user that you *think* might be the another user, this does not mean you should flag it. Having multiple accounts is not against the rules. It is the 2 accounts interacting, or using 1 account to avoid the restriction posed on another that is (such as creating a new account to avoid a question ban).